# What are the use cases for write-only and write-execute files?

Tags: files, permissions

I understand use cases for `r--` and `r-x` permissions, but not for the `-w-` and `-wx` ones.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples or is this purely a theoretical question?  Also, are you referring to *u*, *g* or *o* permissions?  (For example, I can think of a use case where a group requires write access, but not read access so although all members can update a file, they can't read each other's updates).

Comment: @EightBitTony How are the results collected into same file then? Do you have some ref for your example case?

Comment: @Pandya that gives me information about chmod and its parameters. I am looking for real world cases where we'd use them.

Comment: I did a search for possible question/answer. Didn't find. This question has little bit bigger scope. I hope!

Comment: Aspects of Unix's design that go all the way back to V7, like these permission bits, often allow you to do things that aren't useful, because it was simpler/easier to *implement* the system that way.  For instance, having read/write/execute be a bit mask, interpreted literally, is simpler than having some bits imply others.

Answer (score 6):

`-w-` can be useful for fifos or files that can only be opened in *append* mode (`chattr +a` on Linux).

```
prw--w--w- me me /var/run/sendstufftome
```

Would allow others to send data, which a dedicated process running as `me` (but noone else) would read.

It's also common for `tty` devices:

```
$ ls -l "$TTY"
crw--w---- 1 stephane tty 136, 25 Jan 18 14:06 /dev/pts/25
$ mesg n
$ ls -l "$TTY"
crw------- 1 stephane tty 136, 25 Jan 18 14:07 /dev/pts/25
```

It's writable by the `tty` group (or everybody on some systems) so applications like `write` or `wall` (setgid `tty` executables) can send you messages.

---

`-wx` would make sense for some directories:

```
$ ls -dl /var/lib/php5/sessions
drwx-wx-wt 4 root root 4096 Aug 25  2014 /var/lib/php5/sessions
```

That directory is world writable, but nobody knows what files are in there (but `root`). The idea is that one process only knows about the files it has put in there. Typically, file names would be hard to guess random ones (like php sessions files), (one process could find out about the files currently opened by other processes by the same user by looking in `/proc/*/fd` though).

Comment: Didn't consider the FIFOs. Good call!

Comment: It could be used on a device node... maybe a serial interface for logging on an otherwise air-gapped system :).

Comment: @sourcejedi, good point! Reminded me of tty devices.

Comment: Even an append mode file is useful if used to log something - it can be DOSed by causing it to fill up the filesystem, but this a) is rather evident and b) does not allow destruction of the already written information.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to a file, I can't think of a well-known situation where a user would be permitted to write to a file, but not read it. Also, having the execute bit for a file set without the read bit set is pointless since the shell needs to read it in order to execute it.

Now in regards to directories, a possible scenario could be some security through obscurity-- perhaps an anonymous FTP user. `-w-` would allow a user to update a folder's content's (i.e. insert a file) and `-wx` would allow that plus the ability to `cd` to the folder (perhaps, as a starting location for the user)...but **not listing the content's of the directory**, which requires the read bit be set on the directory (perhaps, we don't want them to see *other* user's files).

Comment: No, `-w-` would not allow anything on a directory. You'd also need `x` to do anything with files in there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point.  I think it might technically allow `touch` on the directory, updating its modification time :P.

Comment: You are correct, sir! You need both bits set.

Comment: @sourcejedi `touch` is only permitted if the parent directory is writable.

Comment: Hmm, actually I can't manage to forbid it either way :).  Using filesystem ext4.

Comment: Really? That's surprising! What happens if you type: `cd /tmp && mkdir -p test1/test2 && chmod 400 test1 && touch test1/test2`?

Comment: test2 should be inaccessible? It is!

Comment: Same here! (as expected)